# attach_file option in Helium Scripts

Tags: helium

I am pretty new in Helium Scripts. I am trying to use attach_file option as mentioned in API documentation of Helium. But it does not attach the file.

Syntax I am using: attach_file("C:\xxx/xxx.csv", to="File name:")

Please guide me.
Thanks

SP

Answer (score 2):

Well the way you are trying to attach a file is not right. The right approach should be following

```
attachFile("c:/test.txt", to("Please select a file:"));
```

So in the above syntax **attach_file** this should be **attachFile**
(**"C:\xxx/xxx.csv"**, follow **C:/xxx/xxx.csv** format 
 **to="File name:"** Here instead of file name there should be  **String, WebElement, HTMLElement or Point** )

So the final findings is syntax for **`attaching file is attachFile("file path from where you want to attach", to("WebElement, HTMLElement or Point" where you want to submit))`**

Comment: Nahar Thanks for your reply. But I am sorry I didn't get you. Do you mean the syntax should be **attachFile(C:/test.csv, to("File name:"))**

Comment: Also attachFile is for Java, Python uses **attach_file("c:/test.txt", to="Please select a file:")** .

Comment: any help in this appreciated. I need it very badly.

Answer (score 0):

in case anybody needs it now for Python. This is an excerpt from helium docstring:

```
attach_file("c:/test.txt", to="Please select a file:")
```